# Listen for update or insert in SQL Server from a separate program

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, eventtrigger

I require to listen for updates or inserts for a particular table in my SQL Server.
Most of the examples i saw or found are mainly with regards to confirming a transaction that has taken place in the DB thus having the command and a trigger tied within the same code.
However, I'll like to have a separate program that has multiple threads writing to the table, while the other program is listening to the table and triggering events to get details of the newly updated row for processing. Is this possible? or should I be integrating both programs to make things easier? They're written in different languages but accessing the same DB.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the documentation.

THere are multiple ways to go around to it:

- SQL Server indeed has CHANGE TRACKING which will do that - you can at minimum regularly poll for what has changed.
- Besides that you can use triggers to write a change log into a separate table that you pull.
- You can also use message queueing with message broker to send messages to a listening connection that describe what has been updated.

Finally

- You can rework this architecture to follow standard and use an application server to handle data writes and notifications. VERY little software that I know of does track changes in the database - mostly because the use of an application server is more efficient and standard for like 15 or more years now.